# How to keep track of changes happening inside mongodb and get all data based on that in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a FormBody.js component with the help of which I create a form and submit the details to my backend server made using express.js. Following is the code snippet:

```
const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        author: "",
        message: "",
        imageFile: ""
    })

const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(postData);
        createPost(postData);
        clear();
    }
```

This is working perfectly fine but when I want to get all of my posts from mongodb to my another component which is PostsBody.js, I don't have anything to keep track of "postData" state as mentioned above in the code snippet as it was in other component (FormBody.js). **So right now, I have to reload the React app every time in order to see new posts**.
This is inside PostsBody.js component:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
            setPosts(allPosts);
        }
        getData();
    }, []);
```

**So I need to pass [postData] inside this dependency array of useEffect in order to keep track of changes**, How can I do that?

Comment: One way to handle this problem is to use the `Context API`. Keep `posts` state in the Context and whenever you create a new post, call the `setPosts` function to append the newly created post to the `posts` array. Updating the `posts` array will cause the components consuming the Context to re-render with the new `posts` data.

Comment: @Yousaf okay, can you show an example here to convert this into contextAPI, a code snippet would be really helpful !

Comment: See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-austin-k8ncu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) which makes a POST request to jsonplaceholder API and if the request is succcessful, new post is also shown on the frontend.

Comment: @Yousaf Thank you brother ! That's what I wanted. Actually I found a way to keep track of postData and setPostData instead of posts and setPosts, that's also working great. I just want to know will my solution be inefficient because it keeps track of setPostData like whenever new post is being created, postData will be updated and hence I will call fetch api.

Comment: No, its not inefficient. Input components in React should be [controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: @Yousaf Hey, I got a problem, somehow it's not working and in your demo you're not fetching data from an api which is connected to mongodb, can you help with this, I created context :
`const { postData } = useContext(PostsContext);

    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const allPosts = await getAllPosts();
            setPosts(allPosts);
        }
        getData();
    }, [postData]);
    })`
But it still doesn't work, I have to reload in order to see new post and deleted post !